# подключение к устройству по RS232

Tags: python, rs232, pyserial

Имеется сортировщик банкнот c интерфейсом RS232 (D Sup 9 pins). Необходимо сделать скрипт запроса на Python, который бы выдавал ответ от устройства. Задача, узнать, способен ли он вообще выдавать информацию какую либо. С родным софтом он может только отдавать информацию, работает . По спецификации TXD и RTX сигналы имеются. Выяснил, что надо использовать библиотеку serial, но запрос не получается составить корректный. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так дело в том, что протокола не знаете или с pyserial не понимаете, как работать?

Comment: машина понимает 16ти ричный код. Не знаю какой командой к ней подключиться, как передать ей команды.

Answer (score 0):

Существует протокол общения с устройством, в котором описано, какие есть команды, и в каком формате приходят ответы.

Посылаются и передаются байты информации, как их интерпретировать - зависит от этого самого протокола.

Часто команды для удобства выглядят как ANSI-строки типа `"COUNT?"0x13`  с ответами вроде `"COUNT=666"0x13`. Нужно техническое описание протокола, попробуйте поискать его для своего устройства.

Если никакой информации не найдётся, можно перехватывать поток данных между родной программой и устройством с помощью программ вроде AccessPort или PortMon (эта только для 32-битных windows) и вычислять нужные команды и формат ответа. Для этого требуется некоторый опыт, и весь протокол так не определить (например, сообщения об ошибках)

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM11', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
  parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout = 2 )
ser.isOpen()
ser.write(outbuf)
inbuf = ser.read(...)
```

Comment: Вот хар-ки подключения (1) Electrical Characteristics - RS232C, (2) Connector Type
Connector: D Sub 9 Pins (male)
Спецификация есть, команды и ответы тоже. Я не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте с готовой терминальной программой вроде Terminal 1.9b - соединитесь, пошлите команды, посмотрите ответы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению данное ПО не возможно поставить в нашей организации(

Comment: Кусочек кода для начала положил

Comment: Добавил изображение спецификации. Уточните пожалуйста, что выполняет данный код?

Comment: То, что вы привели, прикладного программиста волновать не должно, это техническая спецификация одного из уровней RS232.

Comment: Если Вы в теме, не могли бы посоветовать книги или ресурсы какие почитать? Сколько не искал, нигде нет информации как проходит процесс обращения и получения информации к устройствам.

Comment: Сам не читал - Агуров Последовательные интерфейсы ПК.  [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff802693(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Спасибо. Уточните пожалуйста, какой ответ должен быть после выполнения кода?

Comment: Если вы в outbuf записали команду, то после чтения inbuf будет содержать ответ, если устройство ответит на команду.

Comment: Пробовал подключаться к машинке с помощью Terminal 1.9b, находит порт по которому подключен, при нажатии Connect ошибок нет. Но при попытке отправить хоть что то, ответа нет. Так же пытался через Putty подключиться, просто появляется пустой черный экран консоли, надписей никаких нет. Настройки все брал из спецификации к машинке. Может ли это означать, что ответ эта счётная машина отдавать в принципе не может?

Comment: Cпецификация к машинке в сети есть?

Comment: Скорее всего нет. Если есть возможность, могу на почту отправить?

Comment: Выложите в общедоступное место.

Comment: Положил на г.диск
httpss://drive.google.com/file/d/15gsPD471njepFIWeklXCMh6AelIBB4Zi/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Вы посылаете sense: `ff 01 10 00 00 00 (и здесь по идее контрольная сумма)` ?

Comment: Да, посылал разные команды, ответа нет никакого.